# RequireJS: Do module functions get executed every time the module is imported or just the first time?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I realize I could answer myself with a simple test project (and I may, if no-one chimes in right away), but I couldn't find the answer anywhere on SO or google, and it seems critical:

If I define an AMD module with require.js as such:

```
//a.js
define( ['stuff'], function (Stuff) {
     return { thing: new Stuff() };
}
```

And then I use it in two different other modules as such:

```
// b.js
define( ['a'], function(a) {
    // do something with a's stuff 
});

// c.js
define( ['a'], function(a) {
  //do something else with a's stuff
}
```

Does `a`'s defining function get called (and therefore a new `Stuff` instantiated) each time I require it for another module or does it just get called once, and its output gets cached?

Obviously this is critical in some use-cases, but its not clear from the require.js documentation or other examples I've seen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just tested this out myself, and it looks like the constructor is only run once.

```
// stuff.js
define(function() {
    return function() {
        console.log('making new!');
    };
});

// a.js
define( ['stuff'], function (Stuff) {
     return { thing: new Stuff };
});

// b.js
define( ['a'], function(a) {
});

// c.js
define( ['a'], function(a) {
});

// app.js
define(['b', 'c'], function() {
    console.log('app');
});

// index.html
<html>
<head>
    <script src='requirejs/require.js' data-main='app.js'></script>
</head>
</html>
```

When I open index.html, the console shows:

```
making new!                             stuff.js:3
app                                       app.js:2
```